# Show and hide divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to show divs when the thumbnail is clicked. I am able to show the first div, but for some reason, the next div is not showing. I cannot figure out what I might be missing.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.clickImage').click(function(){
        $('.popUp').hide();
        $('.popUp').eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.popUp{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="projectContainer">
        <div class="imageV clickImage"></div>
        <div class="textVertical">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel tortor sit amet magna condimentum dapibus non quis nulla. Etiam varius pellentesque quam sed faucibus. Ut libero mi, porta ac tincidunt sagittis, porttitor a elit. In non tellus eu mauris tristique gravida. In rutrum arcu ullamcorper risus consequat interdum. Sed rutrum rhoncus dolor. Suspendisse potenti.</div>

        <div class="imageV clickImage"></div>
        <div class="textVertical">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel tortor sit amet magna condimentum dapibus non quis nulla. Etiam varius pellentesque quam sed faucibus. Ut libero mi, porta ac tincidunt sagittis, porttitor a elit. In non tellus eu mauris tristique gravida. In rutrum arcu ullamcorper risus consequat interdum. Sed rutrum rhoncus dolor. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="popUp">Enlarged Image 1</div>
    <div class="popUp">Enlarged Image 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that $(this).index() is returning the right value? If it returns `3` because you clicked on that second clickImage item, there won't be matching `3` in the popups.

Comment: There is no way where you can identify the unique image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try including a selector in the `.index()` method:

```
$(function(){
    $('.clickImage').click(function(){
        $('.popUp').hide();
        $('.popUp').eq($(this).index(".clickImage")).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is doing what you are intending for it to do.

I would use a `dataImageId` attribute or something similar to uniquely identify the images.

Answer (score 0):

your index is 2 as selected, use something like this:

```
$('.clickImage').click(function () {
       var i=$('.clickImage').index(this);
       $('.popUp').hide();
       $('.popUp').eq(i).show();
});
```

index is 0 based.

Note that the first returns 0 as it is the first div, and 2 on the second as it is the third div, so you need to isolate to the divs with the .clickImage class

Here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/zfZE2/

Comment: hey mark, this is a pretty interesting approach too. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Your first clickable `clickImage` will work because it will return `index:0.`

Which is the right corresponding popup.

But for the second `clickImage` it will return index:2, which does not have a corresponding popup. Only 0 and 1 are present.

This is because `.textVertical` is also seen as a sibling of `clickImage`, thus the 2nd clickImage you clikc will be the 3rd sibling (index).

Change

```
  $('.popUp').eq($(this).index()).show();
```

To

```
  $('.popUp').eq($(this).index('.clickImage')).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rNSLE/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.clickImage').click(function(){
        $('.popUp').hide();
    $(this).next().next().show();
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.popUp{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="projectContainer">
        <div class="imageV clickImage"></div>
        <div class="textVertical">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel tortor sit amet magna condimentum dapibus non quis nulla. Etiam varius pellentesque quam sed faucibus. Ut libero mi, porta ac tincidunt sagittis, porttitor a elit. In non tellus eu mauris tristique gravida. In rutrum arcu ullamcorper risus consequat interdum. Sed rutrum rhoncus dolor. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
    <div class="popUp">Enlarged Image 1</div>

        <div class="imageV clickImage"></div>
        <div class="textVertical">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel tortor sit amet magna condimentum dapibus non quis nulla. Etiam varius pellentesque quam sed faucibus. Ut libero mi, porta ac tincidunt sagittis, porttitor a elit. In non tellus eu mauris tristique gravida. In rutrum arcu ullamcorper risus consequat interdum. Sed rutrum rhoncus dolor. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
    <div class="popUp">Enlarged Image 2</div>
</div>
```